# Legend with colors for patchcollection

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have patches that are colored by a scalar value (integer). Now I'd like to create a legend giving names to the patches of a certain color/integer value. Here is what I tried so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches = []
cvect = []
for kx in range(10):
    for ky in range(10):
        patches.append(Polygon([(kx,ky),(kx,ky+1),(kx+1,ky+1),(kx+1,ky)]))
        cvect.append(((kx*ky)%6))

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')


pc = PatchCollection(patches,edgecolors='none',cmap=cmap)
pc.set_array(np.array(cvect))
ax.add_collection(pc)

clist = list(set(cvect))
handles = []
for col in clist:
    handles.append(Polygon([(0,0),(10,0),(0,-10)],color=cmap(col),
                           label='Material %i'%(col)))

plt.legend(handles=handles)

ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])

fig.savefig('fig')
plt.close(fig)
```

But the colors in the legend do not match the colors of the patches with the same integer value. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a normalization for the values to supply to the colormap. Ideally you supply this normalization already to the Collection `pc`. Then you can access the colors via `pc.cmap(pc.norm(clist))`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches = []
cvect = []
for kx in range(10):
    for ky in range(10):
        patches.append(Polygon([(kx,ky),(kx,ky+1),(kx+1,ky+1),(kx+1,ky)]))
        cvect.append(((kx*ky)%6))

cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
norm = plt.Normalize(min(cvect), max(cvect))

pc = PatchCollection(patches,edgecolors='none',cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
pc.set_array(np.array(cvect))
ax.add_collection(pc)

clist = list(set(cvect))

handles = []
for col in clist:
    print pc.norm(col)
    handles.append(Polygon([(0,0),(10,0),(0,-10)],color=pc.cmap(pc.norm(col)),
                           label='Material %i'%(col)))

plt.legend(handles=handles)

ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([0,10])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted!